# Xamarin Forms iOS NoConstructorFoundException with AutoFac when Link All, and infinite build with Don't Link

Tags: c#, ios, xamarin, xamarin.forms, autofac

I'm facing a perplexing issue while building and deploying my Xamarin Forms app for iOS on a physical iPhone. The app builds and deploys successfully for Android, and it also works on the iOS simulator. However, when I set the linker to "Link All," I encounter a NoConstructorFoundException related to AutoFac.

If I switch the linker to "Don't Link," the exception disappears, but then the build process becomes infinite, and I'm unable to deploy the app on a physical iPhone.

To summarize:

Android: Works fine.
iOS Simulator: Works fine with "Don't Link."
iOS Physical iPhone:
"Link All": NoConstructorFoundException with AutoFac.
"Don't Link": Infinite build, unable to deploy.
I have verified that my AutoFac registrations are correct and that there are no issues with the dependencies.

I'm seeking guidance on how to resolve this issue and successfully deploy the app on a physical iPhone with the linker set to "Link All."

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you in advance!

Output below:

```
/Users/mateusz/shftrun/SHFTRUN/SHFTRUN/SHFTRUN.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone13.2-16.1.2/mtouch-cache/registrar.m(35506,17): warning G3E9910A3: auto property synthesis will not synthesize property 'extrapolate' declared in protocol 'CIPhotoEffect' [-Wobjc-protocol-property-synthesis]
@implementation CoreImage_CIPhotoEffect {
                ^
/Applications/Xcode.app/Contents/Developer/Platforms/iPhoneOS.platform/Developer/SDKs/iPhoneOS17.0.sdk/System/Library/Frameworks/CoreImage.framework/Headers/CIFilterBuiltins.h:417:30: note: property declared here
  @property (nonatomic) bool extrapolate NS_AVAILABLE(14_0, 17_0);
                             ^
/Users/mateusz/shftrun/SHFTRUN/SHFTRUN/SHFTRUN.iOS/obj/iPhone/Debug/device-builds/iphone13.2-16.1.2/mtouch-cache/registrar.m:35583:1: note: add a '@synthesize' directive
@end
^
1 warning generated.
```

Comment: [Related issue?](https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/1398)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, the thing was that Apple didn't allow to select "Don't link" or "Link only SDKs", but when selecting "Link all" the Autofac couldn't access other projects, so it was enough to just use --linkskip for all the project used in AutoFac :D